# Flutter - Flexible with column inside doesn't take max column height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-widget, flutter-column

I'm having problems with flex widget with a column inside where the children have a fixed height (constrained to min and max).

I have to build a screen with a column with many rows as children and each row has some column children and this column has widgets with restricted height.

I want each row to fit the maximum height of the inner column and at the same time all rows to fit the full height of the screen.

I mean, I want the children height has priority over his parent.

EDIT: I attached an image and the code to see the problem.

```
class SecheduleDatatable extends StatelessWidget {
  final DateTime initDate;
  final int dayTreshold;
  final List<ActivityItem> items;
  final bool buildHeaders;

  SecheduleDatatable({
    required this.items,
    required this.initDate,
    required this.dayTreshold,
    this.buildHeaders = false,
  });

  final double spaceBetween = 64;
  final double leftPadding = 32;
  double minItemHeight = 100;
  double maxItemHeight = 150;
  double fontSize = 45;
  double headerHeight = 120;

  void _initSizes(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (screenWidth > 4000) {
      fontSize = 100;
      minItemHeight = 0;
      maxItemHeight = 180;
      headerHeight = 180;
    } else if (screenWidth > 1920) {
      fontSize = 45;
      minItemHeight = 60;
      maxItemHeight = 120;
      headerHeight = 120;
    } else {
      fontSize = 25;
      minItemHeight = 0;
      maxItemHeight = 80;
      headerHeight = 80;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _initSizes(context);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Flexible(child: _createColumns()),
        ..._createRows(),
      ],
    );
  }

  bool hasToExpand(String time) {
    final days = _createDays(true);
    days.addAll(_createDays(false));
    final groupedByTimeSort = items.groupBy((p0) => p0.dateFormated);

    for (DateTime date in days) {
      final tempItems = groupedByTimeSort[time]
          ?.where((element) => element.date.getInitDay() == date.getInitDay())
          .toList();
      if (tempItems != null && tempItems.length > 1) return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  Widget _createColumns() {
    final days = _createDays(true);
    days.addAll(_createDays(false));

    return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: _clock()),
              Expanded(flex: 3, child: _header(days[0].formatHeaderDate())),
              Expanded(flex: 3, child: _header(days[1].formatHeaderDate())),
            ],
          )),
          /*  Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ), */
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              Expanded(flex: 4, child: _header(days[2].formatHeaderDate())),
              Expanded(flex: 4, child: _header(days[3].formatHeaderDate())),
              Expanded(child: Container())
            ],
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _createRows() {
    final days = _createDays(true);
    days.addAll(_createDays(false));
    final groupedByTimeSort = items.groupBy((p0) => p0.dateFormated);

    Widget _getItemByDate(String time, DateTime date) {
      final maybeItems = groupedByTimeSort[time]
          ?.where((element) => element.date.getInitDay() == date.getInitDay());
      if (maybeItems != null) {
        return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: maybeItems
                .map((e) => hasToExpand(time)
                    ? Flexible(child: _item(e, kSpacing / 2))
                    : Flexible(child: _item(e, 0)))
                .toList());
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    }

    Widget _getItem(String time, int pos, int flex) {
      return Expanded(flex: flex, child: IntrinsicHeight(child: _getItemByDate(time, days[pos])));
    }

    final rows = groupedByTimeSort.keys.map((time) {
      final row = Flexible(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(child: _hour(time)),
                _getItem(time, 0, 3),
                _getItem(time, 1, 3),
              ],
            ),
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                _getItem(time, 2, 4),
                _getItem(time, 3, 4),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
              ],
            ),
          ))
        ],
      )));

      /* final row = IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(children: [
        Expanded(child: _hour(time)),
        ...days.map((date) => Expanded(flex: 3, child: _getItemByDate(time, date))).toList()
      ])); */

      return row;
    }).toList();

    return rows;
  }

  Widget _item(ActivityItem item, double spacing) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(spacing),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: item.activityModel!.color, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            item.activityModel!.getTitle(),
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: fontSize),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _emptyItem() {
    return Container(
        // constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minItemHeight, maxHeight: maxItemHeight),
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacing / 2),
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          child: Text(
            "",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: fontSize),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _clock() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kSpacing, vertical: 4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Icon(
            FeatherIcons.clock,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _hour(String time) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kSpacing, vertical: 4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black54, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          child: Text(
            time,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: fontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _header(String text) {
    return Container(
        height: headerHeight,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacing / 2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black54, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Text(
              text,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: fontSize),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  List<DateTime> _createDays(bool first) {
    final days = first ? [initDate] : [initDate.add(Duration(days: dayTreshold ~/ 2))];
    for (var i = first ? 1 : dayTreshold ~/ 2;
        i < (first ? dayTreshold ~/ 2 : dayTreshold - 1);
        i++) {
      days.add(days.last.add(Duration(days: 1)));
    }

    return days;
  }
}
```

I want that the parent row take height of column child. Notice the rows are flexible to fit responsiveness to screen changes.

So really, in summarize,  I want the rows are responsiveness but its inner columns get max height.

Sorry is not easy to explain it.

[image]

Comment: will you post an image of the desire results

Answer (score 0):

I added singlechildscrollview and I set the height of the container for the column items at 320 for four items of 80.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

```
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
      
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
       scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      home: Test_Flexible(),
    );
  }
}

class Test_Flexible extends StatefulWidget {
  Test_Flexible({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test_Flexible> createState() => _Test_FlexibleState();
}

class _Test_FlexibleState extends State<Test_Flexible> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test Flexible"),) ,body: 
    SingleChildScrollView(child:
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.orange,
          )),

        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            height: 320,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child:(Column(children:[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ),
            ]))
          )),
      
          Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          )),

      ],)
    ])
    ,));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it without a scrollview. I need the whole Column adapts to screen.

Comment: The only way to not use a scrollview is to have a fixed sized window.  how will you do that